# C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls

I have been tasked with creating a somewhat hierarchical datagridview for my company. I heavily modified one from Syed Shanu that is posted here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848637/Nested-DataGridView-in-windows-forms-csharp. I'm almost done (data loads properly, etc.), however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the detail grid to move when I scroll. It's a drawn on rectangle and I'm looking for a way to somehow bind it to the master grid so it scrolls up and down with the regular grid. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code that draws the rectangle:

```
private void masterDGVs_CellContentClick_Event(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewImageColumn cols = (DataGridViewImageColumn)MasterDGVs.Columns[0];
        MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = Image.FromFile(@"expand.png");
        if (e.ColumnIndex == gridColumnIndex)
        {
            if (ImageName == @"expand.png")
            {
                DetailDGVs.Visible = true;
                ImageName = @"toggle.png";
                MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
                String FilterExpression = MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[FilterColumnName].Value.ToString();
                MasterDGVs.Controls.Add(DetailDGVs);
                Rectangle DGVRectangle = MasterDGVs.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, e.RowIndex, true);
                DetailDGVs.Size = new Size(MasterDGVs.Width - 48, DetailDGVs.PreferredSize.Height - 16);
                DetailDGVs.Location = new Point(DGVRectangle.X, DGVRectangle.Y + 20);
                DataView detailView = new DataView(DetailGridDT);
                detailView.RowFilter = FilterColumnName + " = '" + FilterExpression + "'";
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DetailDGVs.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Error")
                    {
                        row.Cells[5].Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Processed and Complete")
                    {
                        row.Cells[5].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells[5].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ImageName = @"expand.png";
                MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
                DetailDGVs.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DetailDGVs.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I have sort of working by adding:

```
MasterDGVs.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(DetailDGV_Scroll);
DetailDGVs.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(MasterDGV_Scroll);
```

and

```
private void DetailDGV_Scroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int scale = e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines / 5;
        DetailDGVs.Top = DetailDGVs.Top + scale;
    }

    private void MasterDGV_Scroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int scale = e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta / 5;
        MasterDGVs.Top = MasterDGVs.Top - scale;
    }
```

Comment: Alternate solution: Check out Telerik's [`RadGridView`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/overview).

Comment: Yeah my company doesn't want to pay for that. I've got it sort of working, but I'll have to work on it more.

Comment: I've come back to this problem after a few months while working on another grid. It seems to be a problem with the mouse pointer. When you scroll back up the box aligns with the current position of the mouse cursor. I'll be working on it more when I get a chance.